# How to not suppress parts of exception stacktrace in Logs?

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j, slf4j

I am using SLf4J and springboot.
I see that in logs, I see some lines of exception's stacktrace suppressed.

```
at org.x.x.Method$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c5ed3cb4.create(<generated>) ~[app-core-0.9.3-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:?]|
at org.x.x.Method$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$495e8f0c.invoke(<generated>) ~[app-core-0.9.3-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:?]|
... suppressed 9 lines|
at org.x.x.Method$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ddbb65ef.create(<generated>) ~[app-core-0.9.3-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:?]|
... suppressed 2 lines|
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_372]|
... suppressed 7 lines|
... 94 more|Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException|
```

How to NOT suppress these "suppressed X lines" and elaborate the "94 more" in the logs?

Comment: Could you add the current pattern you have in your configuration ?